# Kentico event calendar widget source code

Tags: kentico

I can't find the source code for the html used for the calendar table. I have the webpart, but not the html for the table. I need to strip the inline CSS and attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the markup for the event calendar (obviously this is what you see):

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    Inherits="CMSWebParts_EventManager_EventCalendar" CodeFile="~/CMSWebParts/EventManager/EventCalendar.ascx.cs" %>
<div class="Calendar">
    <cms:CMSCalendar ID="calItems" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
</div>
<div class="EventDetail">
    <cms:CMSRepeater ID="repEvent" runat="server" Visible="false" StopProcessing="true" EnableViewState="false" />
</div>
```

So what you see on the live page is created by `CMSCalendar` control, which leaves in CMS.Controls library, which means you can't modify it unless you have full source code of Kentico.

I'd try to change the appearance of this control with CSS, if CSS doesn't work there is javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Roman. I was hoping to avoid the JS route. it shouldn't be too much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into creating a skin? You can change the css classes used if needed.

[Might help some](http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/default-skin-refresh)

Comment: I have a custom CSS file, but i want to remove the inline css on the table, and add some class names. I can do this with JS easy enough, but would rather avoid using JS to add a class.